# How can I get the git log entry without indenting?

Tags: git

In git I commit

```
git commit -m 'this
quote> is
quote> my
quote> msg
quote> '
```

`git log` shows

```
commit 3d640cbff57a6da500e40bba9dc20fd145975119 (HEAD -> main)
Author: me <me@me.org>
Date:   Fri Nov 5 12:00:22 2021 -0700

    this
    is
    my
    msg
```

but what I want is

```
commit 3d640cbff57a6da500e40bba9dc20fd145975119 (HEAD -> main)
Author: me <me@me.org>
Date:   Fri Nov 5 12:00:22 2021 -0700

this
is
my
msg
```

or to put it another way, I want the log message in a way suitable for copying and pasting into a new log message whereas by default the message is indented so then I have to un-indent it manually before being able to actually use it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`git log` has the `--format=format:%B` option which will give you the raw commit message without indents.

To get it to look like what you have in your example, it would be

```
git log --format=format:"commit %H %d%nAuthor: %an <%ae>%nDate: %aD%n%n%B"
```

Comment: strange, i had originally tried `git log "--format=format:%b"` and it printed nothing even though the docs suggest it should print something but anyway `git log "--format=format:%B"` works

Comment: @gman: your log message, "this\nis\nmy\nmessage" (with three newlines embedded), is all one *subject line*. The subject line ends with a blank line—a pair of newlines with nothing between them—after which the rest of the message is the *body*. The %B directive prints the subject-and-body, the %s directive prints the subject only, and the %b directive prints the body only. Since you have no body, only a subject, your %b directive prints nothing.

Comment: This is all purely convention: everything `%B` prints is the actual commit message, and the idea of it being a "subject" and "body" is an ex-post-facto *interpretation*. But it's built into Git, and a lot of people like it, so you might wish to consider adopting it yourself. It comes from the old emailing-patches-around work-flow that Linus Torvalds was using when he wrote Git.

Answer (score 5):

The shortest command line I found is:

```
git log --pretty=e
```

which is a shorthand for:

```
git log --pretty=email
```

And this also works for `git show`:

```
git show --pretty=e
```

Comment: To get only the commit message without any headers you can use `git log --no-walk --format=%B committish` or `git show -s --format=%B committish`.

Comment: To get true binary output of the commit, one can also do `git cat-file commit committish`. It will print Git internal headers such as `tree`, `parent`, `author` and `committer`.

Comment: Thanks! Note `git show --pretty=e ...` works too, maybe worth adding to the answer?